# how to make beautifulsoup encode and decode the contents of a script tag

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautifulsoup to parse html but whenever I hit a page with an inline script tag beautifulsoup encodes the contents but does not decodes it back in the end.

This is the code I use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':

    htmlData = '<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript"> console.log("< < not able to write these & also these >> "); </script> </head> <body> <div> start of div </div> </body> </html>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData)
    #... using BeautifulSoup ...
    print(soup.prettify() )
```

I want this output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   console.log("< < not able to write these & also these >> ");
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   start of div
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

But I get this output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   console.log("&lt; &lt; not able to write these &amp; also these &gt;&gt; ");
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   start of div
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a [bug filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/950459) for this in Beautiful Soup 3.  Looks like the bug persists in Beautiful Soup 4.  You may want to [file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/) a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.html as LH

if __name__ == '__main__':
    htmlData = '<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript"> console.log("< < not able to write these & also these >> "); </script> </head> <body> <div> start of div </div> </body> </html>'
    doc = LH.fromstring(htmlData)
    print(LH.tostring(doc, pretty_print = True))
```

yields

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript"> console.log("< < not able to write these & also these >> "); </script></head>
<body> <div> start of div </div> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
htmlCodes = (
('&', '&amp;'),
('<', '&lt;'),
('>', '&gt;'),
('"', '&quot;'),
("'", '&#39;'),
)

for i in htmlCodes:
    soup.prettify().replace(i[1], i[0])
```

Comment: -1.  A lot wrong with this.  First of all, you call prettify for each iteration, discarding the results of the prior replacement.  Second, you clobber any character entity references that are not in the javascript portion.